# IBOutlet doesn't react to code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iboutlet

I created a `UIImageView` in IB and connected it to an `IBOutlet`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *alertImage;
```

However, the `UIImageView` doesn't react to my code at all. I tried setting the outlet and then changing a property to test:

```
alertImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
alertImage.hidden = YES;
```

But the image didn't disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have already `UIIMageView` as outlet then just don't initialize it again

Comment: You should not alloc+init the same property again. The previous one is lost/released which was your outlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-initializing `alertImage`, so it's not connected to the "original" one defined in IB anymore.

Simply just use:

```
alertImage.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: so 3000-30* after this answer :p

Answer (score 4):

Drop that line: `alertImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];`
Write only `alertImage.hidden = YES;`

Answer (score 2):

You declared your IBOutlet as a property, so why don't you use it as a property?

Try `self.alertImage.hidden = YES;`